# How to replace value of key in json file using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to replace the following json key value pair,

```
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"HTML", to 
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"XML"
```

using sed.

Here is the sed command I'm using,

```
sed -i 's/^\(\"\$\$RESULT_REPORTER\$\$\"*:*\).*$/\1\"XML\"/' /path/to/file
```

But the problem with this is I'm not able to retain the comma at the end and its giving me json parsing error.
How do I retain the comma after replace the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the comma to the replacement:

```
$ sed -i 's/^\(\"\$\$RESULT_REPORTER\$\$\"*:*\).*$/\1\"XML\",/' file
###                                                 HERE ---^
```

**Edit**

```
$ cat file
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"HTML",
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"HTML"

$ sed 's/^\("$\$RESULT_REPORTER\$\$":"\)[^"]*/\1XML/' file
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"XML",
"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"XML"
```

Comment: What if the json string doesnt contain 'comma' at the end?

Comment: Thanks for reply @sudo_O. But it doesnt seem to work,                                 
    `#cat test`
    `"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"HTML",`
    
    `# sed 's/^\(\"\$\$RESULT_REPORTER\$\$\"*:*\)[^"]\(",?\)$/\1XML\2/' test`
    `"$$RESULT_REPORTER$$":"HTML",`