# Replace Content in place using sed in a JSON file

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed, replace

My `JSON` file is as follows:

```
{
 "Name":"SA",
 "Password":"yyyyy",
 "Mappings" : {
 "RegionMap" : {
     "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "xxxxxx" },
     "us-east-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
     "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
     "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ca-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
     "eu-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
     "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
     "eu-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ap-south-1"     : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ap-southeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
     "ap-northeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
     "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "" }       
    }
  }
}
```

My `task` is to update the value of the `AMI` key of `us-east-1` in the given `json` file. I have used [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) to solve this issue . Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061585/update-contents-of-file-via-jq-using-redirection-operator). I am having problems with [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) no being stable on my `windows` server machine. So now I want to obtain the same using `sed` commands.

My `expected output` is as follows

```
{
"Name":"SA",
"Password":"yyyyy",
"Mappings" : {
"RegionMap" : {
   "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "abcd" },
   "us-east-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ca-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-south-1"     : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "" }       
   }
 }
}
```

I have referred many questions relating to this on `stackoverflow` relating to this issue but I am unable to get the desired output. The links of the questions referred are as follows

1. [Find and replace text within a file using commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands)
2. [Find and replace for JSON with sed or awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281538/find-and-replace-for-json-with-sed-or-awk)
3. [How to replace value of key in json file using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272244/how-to-replace-value-of-key-in-json-file-using-sed)
4. [Use Sed to find and replace json field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239522/use-sed-to-find-and-replace-json-field)
5. [Replace value in json during run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868649/replace-value-in-json-during-run-time)

Can somebody help me with this? Also is it possible that I can use environment variables value for replacing the contents of the file in place? If so, how?

Edit

I have already got the answer using jq. The link is mentioned above. Since jq is unstable on my windows server machine I am trying to achieve the same using sed commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update contents of file via jq using redirection operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061585/update-contents-of-file-via-jq-using-redirection-operator)

Comment: I have mentioned about that in my question.. jq is unstable in my windows machine and I want to achieve the same using sed commands

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a soap box of mine, but `sed` does *not* modify files in place.  The `--in-place` option of gnu-sed is completely misnamed, as it does *not* modify the file, but creates a new one.  If you want to edit a file, use `ed`.  (`sed` is the streaming version of `ed`).
Now, also with the caveat that using either `ed` or `sed` to edit json data is a bad idea, you might try this (non-robust) solution:

```
printf '/us-east-1/s/: ".*"/: "abcd"/\nw\nq\n' | ed input
```

(This works for your input, but relies on the space between the `:` and the `"`, and is fragile because of that.)

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to achieve it in sed is to create the following sed file

```
/AMI/ {
 /us-east-1/ {
    s/"AMI".*/"AMI" : "abcd" },/
 }
}
```

And execute it as such

```
sed -f <above_file.sed> <json file>
```

If `xxxxxx` is the actual text in the file and you want to replace it, use the following :

```
/AMI/ {
 /us-east-1/ {
    s/xxxxxx/abcd/
 }
}
```

Comment: But AMI is in RegionMap and RegionMap is in Mappings Object. Will the same sed  work? Also can you give a sed in command line fashion?